# Connect MySql with Servlet for login page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

How to connect MySql dataBase with servlet for login page?
For now in servlet I have code for predefined username (gogikole) and password (1234)

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");

            if (username.equals("gogikole") && password.equals("1234")) {
                response.sendRedirect("mainMenu.jsp");
                return;
            }
```

but how to check is username and password are correct for some other users from database?
For example username: konsta, password: 4321

I have code like this:

Login Servlet

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.*;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (username.equals("gogikole") && password.equals("1234")) {
            response.sendRedirect("mainMenu.jsp");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="LoginServlet">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>User name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Also I already added mysqlconnector to Eclipse.

Comment: Well, you have `if (username.equals("gogikole") && password.equals("1234")) {` - you ***could*** add `if (username.equals("konsta") && password.equals("4321")) {` - but that doesn't seem like a particularly scalable solution; if only there was somewhere you could store relational data types like usernames and (hashed) passwords....

Comment: Follow a tutorial for JPA or JDBC

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yea, but what to do if there is many users, like 100 or more? :D

Answer (score 0):

First,you should connect to mysql use MysqlConnection.

Then,create a statement use sql like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password`.Then execute it.

You will got a resultSet which contains the results of match user,of course,if username or password is wrong,the resultSet is empty.

The key to slove your problem is you should query to database instade of `username.equals("gogikole") && password.equals("1234")`

Example:

```
final String DB_URL = "localhost:3306/db";  //Mysql Address
final String USER = "root";  //mysql username
final String PASS = "123456";//mysql password
final String SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";  //SQL
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
Connection conn = null;  //mysql connection
Statement stmt = null;   //mysql statement
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  //register driver
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS); //get connection
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL); //create statement
//init param
stmt.setString(1,username);
stmt.setString(2,password);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();  //execute query
if(rs.first()){ //finded
    response.sendRedirect("mainMenu.jsp");
    return;
}
```